# How do I get the index of the current Object in an NSEnumerator iteration?

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, xcode, nsenumerator

Question: How do I get the index of the current Object in an NSEnumerator iteration?

(I don't want to keep track of things using an integer counter or use a for loop due to speed reasons. I did it before I just cannot remember how I did it...)

Comment: I would be very surprised if an integer counter affected the speed of your loop. Unless you are iterating billions of items, a simple counter isn’t going to have any noticeable impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doubtful that using an integer counter in a `for` loop will cause speed problems. It is more likely to be slower to try and find the index of a given object from an enumerator than it is to just keep a record of the index yourself. If you want to bypass repeated message dispatch, have a look at NSArray's [`getObjects:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBGGHJ) method.

```
size_t count = [myArray count];
id *objects = calloc(count, sizeof(id));

[myArray getObjects:objects range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];

// if you have a very large count, you'll save doing an
// "objectAtIndex:" for each item.

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    [objects[i] doSomething];

free(objects);
```

You'll probably only see a minimal performance difference for incredibly large arrays, but don't underestimate the optimisations under the hood. Even the documentation for `getObjects:range:` discourages using this technique for this purpose.

NSArray's [`indexOfObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDHGFB) will iterate over all the elements until one returns `YES` from `isEqual:` message (which may include further message sending).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for an index, so we can assume that you are using an array.  If so:

```
[array indexOfObject:currentObject];
```

will work for most cases (but not all).  It would be faster overall to switch to using a normal for loop with an int counter, however.